# How to remove all symlinks in usr/local/include from a determined path

Tags: swift, ruby, symlink, xcode-command-line-tools

I was having some issues to compile a Ruby library where it has some C++ dependencies. I read somewhere that adding the code below fixes the issue:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/* /usr/local/include/
```

But now when I run `swift build` I get this error:

```
/Users/me/Repository/myproject-swift: error: manifest parse error(s):
/usr/local/include/libxml2/libxml/module.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'libxml2'
module libxml2 [system] [extern_c] {
       ^
/usr/local/include/libxml2/module.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module libxml2 [system] [extern_c] {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'AppleTextureEncoder'
module AppleTextureEncoder [system] [extern_c] {
```

The solution suggested by a friend is to delete all the symlinks from `usr/local/include` when I list it the number of symlinks is massive. What I can do to remove the symlinks from the path below?

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/*`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To remove all unwanted symlink for that path provided, run:

```
find usr/local/include -lname '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/*' -delete
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39341/404343